# Out of container JNDI data source

Tags: java, datasource, jndi

I would like to configure a DataSource using JNDI in a Java SE app. What is the best way to do this?

So far, I've come across 2 projects:

1. [Apache Naming](http://directory.apache.org/subprojects/naming/using.html). The project page has a specific example for configuring a data source, but it looks like the project is super old and no longer active.
2. [JBossNS](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/JBossNS). It looks like it's easy to configure a local-only JNDI using `LocalOnlyContextFactory`, but I haven't found any docs on how to actually configure a data source.

If possible, I would like to also configure the data source with a JTA transaction manager (using JOTM?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why are you using JNDI for this? It's not that it's a bad solution if you have a provider but there are alternatives such as dependency injection (IoC: via [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) or [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)).

The Spring JDBC data access is described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/jdbc.html). The great thing is that you can use Spring to inject a `DataSource` into your code:

```
<bean class="com.my.Persister">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

The data source can be defined using a JNDI-lookup:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MyDataSource" />
```

In a test environment, you could inject the data source directly:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="apache.db.PoolingDataSource">
    <!-- config goes here -->
</bean>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the post. I am writing a component which will be running in a web app, but I would like to also be able to invoke it from plain Java SE command line apps and JUnit tests.

My initial idea was that I should be able to setup the necessary environment (JNDI, DBCP, JTA) so that the component code can always rely on these.

I'm reluctant to introduce a whole new framework such as Spring into the application, but that could be an option. Are there specific Spring documentation pages relating to this that you would recommend?

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide a link and some indication of what to do. Spring JDBC is very powerful

Comment: Thank you for the details. I don't have enough points to mark the answer as helpful :|

Answer (score 4):

These references are pretty old but may help to use jnpserver (JBoss Naming Service provider):

- [Working With JNDI In A J2SE Application](http://ezinearticles.com/?Working-With-JNDI-In-A-J2SE-Application&id=949566)
- [Standalone JNDI server using jnpserver.jar](http://jboss.org/?module=bb&op=viewtopic&t=102727)

Answer (score 3):

A very easy to use solution for stand-alone JNDI is [simple-jndi](https://code.google.com/p/osjava/wiki/SimpleJNDI). It works like a charm as long as you only need it within a single JVM, since it's a library no network server.

Answer (score 1):

The Simple-JNDI version, referenced by klenkes74, is not under active development any more. Because I encountered some issues with it I forked it, did some bug fixes and implemented some new features. I already used the old version not only for testing but in production too because I prefer a Service Locator pattern over Dependency Injection although the latter one is more trendy nowadays.

You can easily use Simple-JNDI to define a DataSource or a connection pool declaratively and get it bound to a JNDI Context.

Define a jndi.properties file in your classpath:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.osjava.sj.SimpleContextFactory
org.osjava.sj.root=[absolute_or_relative_path_to_a_property_file]
```

The property file looks like:

```
type=javax.sql.DataSource
driver=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb
user=testuser
password=testing
```

Now you can access your DataSource from inside your code this way:

```
  InitialContext ctxt = new InitialContext();
  DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctxt.lookup("name_of_your_datasource");
```

For more information see https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI

Comment: Thanks for adding your fork to this answer. I'm using your fork for some time. But I use it in DI mode (I feed the JNDI to a DI framework and use the simple-jndi config files for easy configuration of non-container software to keep the users out of the DI providers config files.