# Java- JNDI service in plain Java

Tags: java, jndi

I have a plain Java project without any server.

I need to get connection object.

I want to use `JNDI service` which will return `JNDI`. How can I do it in plain java.

How to configure the `JNDI service` in simple Java (Java SE).

first time working on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1615417/1113392), you might find some guidance and / or alernatives in it.

Answer (score 1):

Please go though the below link which provides the information you are looking for. It provides a basic information about JNDI and an example of JNDI.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076888/core-java/jndi-overview--part-1--an-introduction-to-naming-services.html